# How to set attributeName to "value"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to assign "value" as attributeName to a jQuery object. However, I am getting the "Object doesn't support this property or method" error. Here is the line:

```
$(rowElem).attr("value","");
```

I think I am getting this error because jQuery treats the word "value" as another method and not as an attribute. I will gladly appreciate help from you guys. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: you are trying to set the value of a NOT existing attribute

Comment: what is `$(rowElem)`?!

Comment: @MaVRoSCy I think you meant element

Comment: Hi @mehdi, this is the value of rowElem:
    `var rowElem = $(xmlHello).get(0).createElement('hi');`

Comment: Hi @MaVRoSCy, by "NOT existing attribute", do you mean that an error is showing up because I am trying to assign an empty string? I think that is not an issue. I tried assigning a non-empty value, for instance, `$(rowElem).attr("value","hello");` and I get the same error. Thanks for your responses! :D

Answer (score 1):

Hi you are doing it wrong , Jquery need a selector whether its id , class or tagname

> for Id you need to add prefix "#" For Class you need to add prefix "."
>   and tag name as it is....

So your fixed code is something like that

```
$("#rowElem").attr("value","My New VAlue");
```

Comment: Since we don't know what the `rowElem` variable contains, that's somewhat speculative.

Comment: most of the case rowElem refereed as class, so can use this
$('.rowElem').attr("value","My New VAlue");

Comment: Thanks for your responses! `rowElem` is not an HTML element here, it is an XML object  declared like this: `var rowElem = $(xmlHello).get(0).createElement('hi');`

Answer (score 0):

When ever you use value I think the only jquery you will use is

```
$(rowElem).val("");
```

It is however, not a good practice to use 'value' as any other attribute, what you can do is with HTML5, make your own attribute as

```
<tr data-value="somevalue" />
```

and use the attribute like

```
$(rowElem).attr("data-value", "");
```

and you can use that attribute's value like

```
var val = $(rowElem).attr("data-value");
```

Comment: Hi @progrAmmar! Unfortunately, using `.val()` is not an option. Here, I am trying to copy an XML's attributes to another XML. "value" is one of those attributes.

Comment: Well that changes the context completely, if you are using normal jQuery to get XML values, I do not think it will be a good idea, You will have to look at parsing XML with jQuery to achieve that in my honest opinion

Comment: I see. In addition, `.setAttribute("value","")` is working properly. It is only with `.attr("value","")` that I am encountering this issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: .setAttribute() is a XML DOM  method and it worked because it parses HTML documents as XML too. That's why it worked. jQuery on the other hand sees val() for input objects only that is most probably why you are having issues with jQuery .attr() function.

Comment: Ohh I see! Thank you very much. That's a big help! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code that we can see. It looks like you don't have jQuery loaded in the DOM. See my tests below.

i.e. If you go to backbonejs.org and type in the following in the console:

```
if(jQuery)
    console.log('jQuery has loaded');
    // logs 'jQuery has loaded'
var rowElem = 'div';
$(rowElem).attr('value', '');
```

It successfully adds 'value' to the divs.

However, if you use a site without jQuery like underscorejs.org, it won't work:

```
if(jQuery)
    console.log('jQuery has loaded');
    // ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
var rowElem = 'div';
$(rowElem).attr('value', '');
// TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'attr'
```

You need to get it access to jQuery and your problem should be solved.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answering. This is my test result:
    >>console.log('jQuery has loaded');
    LOG: jQuery has loaded
This result doesn't change when I step into the function. My guess is that jQuery is treating the word "value" as a reserved word.

Comment: What browser are you using? Your error message makes it sound like it's not recognizing attr(), not an issue with 'value'.

Comment: Have you tried any other jQuery methods? i.e. `$(rowElem).addClass('testing');`

Comment: I'm using IE8. Sorry if you got confused, `attr()` is working properly in my browser, except when I try to set the word "value" as attributeName. As for other jQuery methods, I don't think I can use `.addClass` because I am trying to copy an XML's attributes to another using `.attr()`. "value" is one of the XML's attributes. :)

Comment: I meant to use `.addClass` to verify that you can access jQuery and are hooking up to the right element. It shouldn't matter that it's an xml attribute because then it would just change that to "". I think the problem is IE8.

Answer (score -1):

There is no such attribute in jquery or javascript. Both treats value as a separate function.

You can try using:

```
jquery: $(rowElem).val("urVal");
javascript: rowElement.value = "urVal";
```

Answer (score -1):

use this.. provide value in val

```
$(rowElem).val("value");
```

hope it works...